# Why does :%yc not yank the buffer into register c?

Tags: vim

I want to yank the content of a buffer into the c register.

Since I can yank the entire buffer into the clipboard with a

```
:%y*
```

and the clipboard is accessed through the `*` register, I thought, I should also be able to yank a buffer into register c with a

```
:%yc
```

Yet, it doesn't modify the register.

I also tried

```
:%"cy
```

with no success, either.

Comment: Wouldn't `:help :y` be easier and quicker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a space:

```
:%y c
```

When I try it without the space, I get a helpful error message:

```
E492: Not an editor command: %yc
```

Comment: I got this error message too, but couldn't relate it to the missing space.